# Array split com array_push para múltiplos INSERT no SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array, array-push

Tenho um `foreach` que faz o *loop* nos dados de um arquivo, esse *loop* gera alguns valores que são inseridos numa `array` com `array_push`, preciso quebrar esses valores inseridos nesse `array` para gerar múltiplos `INSERT INTO` pois alguns `INSERT` ficaram com mais de 2500 caracteres.

Código:

```
$dados = array();
foreach ($arquivo->entrada as $xyz):
...
array_push($dados, $valores);
endforeach;

implode(', ', $dados);

print_r(array_chunk($dados, 2, true));
```

Com isso, consigo quebrar os valores a cada 2 entradas do `array` por exemplo.

Mas como eu poderia fazer isso para ter uma *query* com vários `INSERT INTO`?
Não sei como fazer isso adicionando `INSERT INTO 'tabela' VALUES` *VALOR-DO-ARRAY* `;` para cada novo split.

Exemplo de dados adicionados ao `array`:

```
('2615509767','Challenge','','','Portuguese','','')
```

Exemplo de dados obtidos com o `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ('2615509767','Challenge','','','Portuguese','','')
            [1] => ('2178947891','Name','','','Portuguese','','')
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => ('1877844784','City','','','English','','')
        )
)
```

Exemplo de código desejado:

```
INSERT INTO 'tabela' VALUES ('2615509767','Challenge','','','Portuguese','',''), ('2178947891','Name','','','Portuguese','','');
INSERT INTO 'tabela' VALUES ('1877844784','City','','','English','','');
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso no com php?

Comment: Nota, coloquei ```2``` no ```array_chunk``` como exemplo para a questão, minha _query_ de ```INSERT``` tem muitos valores, e consequentemente iria mudar esse valor para se adequar a ela.

Comment: a função `print_r()` passando true retorna uma string como a da pergunta certo? Não seria só concatenar com o restante do script SQL?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam atualizei os dados do ```print_r``` desculpe a discrepância no código. Não sei exatamente como fazer isso, nem lembro como fazer se algum dia soube, por isso cá estou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode percorrer cada array, veja:

Criei uma variável do tipo array.

```
$resultado = [];
```

Siga os passos:

1. Percorre o array pai.

   ```
   for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++)
   ```
2. Defina uma variável com parte do comando.

   ```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO 'tabela' VALUES ";
   ```
3. Percorre o array filho.

   ```
   for($b = 0; $b < count($dados[$a]); $x++)
   ```
4. Verificar se o valor da variável `$b` é maior que zero, se for concatena uma vírgula.

   ```
   if ($b > 0) { $sql .= ', '; }
   ```
5. Concatena o valor.

   ```
   $sql .= $dados[$a][$b];
   ```
6. Verifica se o valor de `$b` é igual ao número de elementos no índice `$a` de `$dados`, caso seja adiciona um ponto e vírgula.

   ```
   if ($b === (count($dados[$a]) -1 )) { $sql .= ";"; }
   ```
7. Adicione o valor da variável `$sql` no array `$resultado`.

   ```
   array_push($resultado, $sql);
   ```

Para finalizar, basta fazer um `implode` adicionando uma quebra de linha:

```
echo implode("\n", $resultado);
```

E terá a saída:

```
INSERT INTO 'tabela' VALUES ('2615509767','Challenge','','','Portuguese','',''), ('2178947891','Name','','','Portuguese','','');
INSERT INTO 'tabela' VALUES ('1877844784','City','','','English','','');
```

#### Código completo:

```
$dados = [
  [
    "('2615509767','Challenge','','','Portuguese','','')",
    "('2178947891','Name','','','Portuguese','','')"
  ],
  [ "('1877844784','City','','','English','','')" ]
];

$resultado = [];
for($a = 0; $a < count($dados); $a++) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO 'tabela' VALUES ";
  for($b = 0; $b < count($dados[$a]); $b++) {
    if ($b > 0) { $sql .= ', '; } // Concatena vírgula
    $sql .= $dados[$a][$b]; // Concatena valor
    if ($b === (count($dados[$a]) -1 )) {
      $sql .= ";"; // Concatena ponto e vírgula
    }
  }
  array_push($resultado, $sql);
}

echo implode("\n", $resultado);
```

Veja funcionando [em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PlainWretchedZettabyte) ou [em ideone.com](https://ideone.com/6zqDhU)

Comment: Consegui o resultado esperado com uma pequena mudança, usando ```$dados = array_chunk($dados, 2);``` e removendo ```(``` e ```)``` da parte do meu código onde adicionava-os ao array, de resto tudo funcionou como descrito acima. :)

Comment: Na verdade eu errei ali, você mesmo disse que os elementos era `('2615509767','Challenge','','','Portuguese','','')`

Comment: Sem problemas, obrigado por corrigir, essa parte dos parêntesis eu poderia mudar caso necessário.